# How to define Column height in MultiTextColumn using itextsharp in asp.net mvc

Tags: itext

I m creating PDF from asp.net mvc. i have needed two Bullet list side by side.each list contain 3 listitem and each have one line length.Currently i m getting both list in one Column like

first cell

second cell

third cell

forth cell

fifth cell

sixth cell

and i have needed

---

**.** First cell 	   **.**Second cell. 
 
 **.** Third cell 		   **.**Fourth cell.
 **.** Fifth column 	   **.**Sixth cell

I hope u got point.i can provide code if needed

Please help in this regard i will b very thankful to you

code is here that causing problem

```
MultiColumnText columns = new MultiColumnText();
columns.AddRegularColumns(36f, doc.PageSize.Width-36f, 24f, 2);
iTextSharp.text.List list = new iTextSharp.text.List();
list.Add("first cell");
list.Add("third cell");
list.Add("fifth cell");
columns.AddElement(list);

iTextSharp.text.List list1 = new iTextSharp.text.List();
list1.Add("second cell");
list1.Add("fourth cell");
list1.Add("sixth cell");
columns.AddElement(list1);

doc.Add(columns); //not displaying desire result
```

Comment: Please provide the shortest amount of code that you've used that can replicate the issue.

Comment: `MultiColumnText` was removed from iTextSharp. You must be using a version that is more than one year old: http://itextpdf.com/history/?branch=53&node=533

Comment: Oh Dmn it was so easy i can pass column height size in Multicolumn constructor.Thnx God i waste alot time in it
@BrunoLowagie  yes i m using .net nughet pakage it is still there.